# While loop is not executing even with conditions swittched, variable boolean is true and doesn't break

Tags: c#, loops

I am coding a tic-tac-toe game and ran into a while-loop problem. This is inside a switch-statement with 2 different cases and there being a random.next() to choose between the 2.

When this while loop condition is unmet, it is supposed to break out into a game win message. The options are either for a function to return true or a variable to. I added the variable inside the executed function just in case.

A string[] game array is first declared and then is filled with whitespaces so it wouldn't turn out as null. This function AllArrFilledEmptySpace(); works with the whitespaces to detect if there is a letter "X" or "O" playing as a spot on the game map.

Here is the while-loop code:

```
public static string[] board { get; set; }

public static bool gameEnd { get; set; }

public static void Run()
        {
            Clear();
            makeArr();
            gameEnd = false;
            ConsoleKey keyPressed;
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = ReadKey(true);
            keyPressed = keyInfo.Key;
            Random rOdd = new Random();
            int odds = rOdd.Next(0, 2);
       

            do
            {
                switch (odds)
                {
                    case 0:

                        while (!gameEnd || !AllArrFilledEmptySpace(board))
                        {


                            Clear();
                            printBoard(board);
                            turnO(board);
                            WriteLine($"\n\nAll Blocks filled: {AllArrFilledEmptySpace(board)}, GameEnd variable: {gameEnd}");
                            ReadKey(true);

                            Clear();
                            printBoard(board);
                            turnX(board);
                            WriteLine($"\n\nAll Blocks filled: {AllArrFilledEmptySpace(board)}, GameEnd variable: {gameEnd}"); ;
                            ReadKey(true);

                        }




                        break;
                    case 1:

                        while (!gameEnd || !AllArrFilledEmptySpace(board))
                        {

                            Clear();
                            printBoard(board);
                            turnO(board);
                            WriteLine($"\n\nAll Blocks filled: {AllArrFilledEmptySpace(board)}, GameEnd variable: {gameEnd}");
                            ReadKey(true);

                            Clear();
                            printBoard(board);
                            turnX(board);
                            WriteLine($"\n\nAll Blocks filled: {AllArrFilledEmptySpace(board)}, GameEnd variable: {gameEnd}"); ;
                            ReadKey(true);

                        }

                        break;

                }
                
                } while (!gameEnd) ;

                winMessage();
                ReadKey(true);

            }
```

Here is the function  AllArrFilledEmptySpace();

```
 public static bool AllArrFilledEmptySpace(string[] board)
        {
            
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < board.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!board[i].Equals(" "))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count == 9)
            {
                gameEnd = true;
                return true;
            }

                return false;
        }

public static string[] makeArr()
        {
            board = new string[9];


            for (int i = 0; i < board.Length; i++)
            {
                string q = " ";
                board[i] = q;
            }
            
            return board;
        }
```

Comment: I think you want `!gameEnd && !AllArrFilledEmptySpace(board)` or `!(gameEnd || AllArrFilledEmptySpace(board))` (they are logically equivalent)

Comment: In other words, you want the loop to end if `gameEnd` is true OR `AllAre...` is true, so your while should be the logical negation of that.

Comment: Agree. In general, try to avoid boolean expressions that include multiple "not" operators. The human brain isn't as intuitive understanding those.

Comment: The problem is not what is inside the while loop, it’s what is executing after, when the loop breaks and the GameMessage(); function then executes. Maybe how my code is called and placed. I will have to run through my whole code…

Answer (score 3):

If the game is not ended (`!gameEnd`) then `AllArrFilledEmptySpace(board)` will not be called because there is a or (`||`) between them.

And when `AllArrFilledEmptySpace()` is not called `gameEnd` will never be set to `true` and `AllArrFilledEmptySpace()` will never be called.

Comment: A few hours later I saw that AllArrFilledEmptySpace() was called in WriteLine(), but that is too late, there will be an extra round.